# Yeshiva University RIETS Semicha Yorei and Yadin

Tags: beit-din-court, yeshiva-school, semicha

1) Who is eligible to join this program? If I learnt my whole "Bachur Years" in ordinary schools and Yeshivot will I be accepted? (I have a diploma and a BTL).

2) What is a classic Seder HaYom for students at Yeshiva University's Semicha Program?  What is learned during this cycle? What times of the day/year?

3) Are students taught the information well enough to go ahead and be tested by the Chief Rabbinate of Israel?

Basically looking for a clear summary of what goes on there, as I know that many fellows on here studied there.

Comment: Why are you asking us instead of asking them?

Comment: אינו דומה תא שמע לתא חזי

Comment: @ Avi M please see https://www.yu.edu/sites/default/files/inline-files/semikhah_requirements_final.pdf

Comment: The YU yadin yadin program is for exceptional scholars and has a limited number of openings each year. My son in law learned in Ner Israel, and the Mir before entering that program. You should first complete the *regular* semicha before you go on to *yadin yadin*. In any case, you need to speak with the rosh yeshiva you studied with first to see how much farther than the BTL you need to go.

Comment: @sabbahillel He learnt in YU?

Comment: @DanielRoss Looking at the files that you point to, and based on what my son in law has told me, that is the regular semicha program. The *Yadin Yadin* is the *Kollel Elyon* program which occurs after one has received the *normal* semicha

Comment: @AviM Yes. But that was before yeshiva in Israel, Ner Israel, and the Mir.

Answer (score 7):

My personal experience in the program gives me the following perspective: Overall, it's an incredible program which empowers the Talmid with tons of time to learn and grow in his Torah and leadership skills, under the guidance of Torah personalities of world renown.

1) Yes, but it's more fluid in many ways if you went through the system via college. Those ways include fitting in with the chevra, amount of time you have to spend on campus, familiarity with the bullet train that is YU and how everything runs, and scholarship awarded upon admittance.

2) Ayen the links in the comments and other answer.

3) Nope, but the pastoral training is of a unique caliber. Listen to the shiurim on YUTorah and note how they do not cover anywhere near enough information (nor do the ten months of yeshiva a year allow) for one to be immediately competent to pass a Rabbanut exam. Compare to the testing requirements on http://smicha.co.il.

Regarding psychology:
Dr. David Pelcovitz and Dr. Norman Blumenthal are renowned veteran psychologists in the Jewish community - they're flown in to speak all over the country and world for halls filled to the max regarding all sorts of issues - and the students in RIETS have the opportunity to learn from them on a weekly basis. Public speaking training can be intensive, and shimush opportunities in the in major synagogues in the tristate area are mandatory. Of course, it all depends on the chosen track. See the docs for details.

Answer (score 3):

You will find most of the answers to your question (except #3) in their [application document](https://www.yu.edu/sites/default/files/inline-files/riets%20application%205776.pdf) and various other [student resources](https://www.yu.edu/riets/student-resources) which are worth reading through in full. You may possibly find the answer to your third question in [this document](https://www.yu.edu/sites/default/files/inline-files/RIETS%20Requirements_0.pdf) which outlines the curriculum and requirements for semikhah